# get all DOM elements with certain name mask

Tags: jquery

I've got several elements on the page. Some of the have name id like this `component1`,`component2` and etc.

How to get all this elements(elements with names which start with `component`) using jquery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/?s=starts+with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `^` selector

```
var elements = $('[id^="component"]')
```

Comment: is there pure javascript equivalent document.getElementBy.... or something? Would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Use wildcards in jQuery selectors:

```
$('name^=component')
```